# Prometheus sum while filtering by label

Tags: openshift, prometheus

In Prometheus I can provide a sum of pod cpu usage that is filtered by namespace:

```
sum(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{namespace='my-namespace'}) by (pod)
```

I want to filter that down further by matching a given label like application=my-app.  Something like the following (which doesn't work):

```
sum(node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{namespace='my-namespace', kube_pod_labels{label_application='my-app'}}) by (pod)
```

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter the pod CPU usage further based on a specific pod label like `application=my-app`, you need to use the `kube_pod_labels` metric to filter by the desired label. You can try like this if it works:

```
sum(
  node_namespace_pod_container:container_cpu_usage_seconds_total:sum_irate{namespace='my-namespace'}
  * on(pod) group_left(label_application)
  kube_pod_labels{label_application='my-app'}
) by (pod)
```

You can read more from [here](https://www.robustperception.io/using-group_left-to-calculate-label-proportions/)

Comment: Since aggregation is done over `pod`, whole filtering can be moved outside too. IMHO, it's easier to read query that way.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure out how to use group_left in the context of labels.  @markalex, could you give an example of how filtering can be moved outside?

Comment: @JerrySeutter, `sum(
node_...:containsum_irate{namespace='my-namespace'}
) by (pod)  * on(pod) group_left(label_application)
  kube_pod_labels{label_application='my-app'}
`